# Event system that automatically detects sender?

Tags: python, events, python-3.x, event-handling

Here's my current event system:

```
class Event(set):    
    def fire(self, sender, **event_args):
        for handler in self:
            handler(sender, *event_args)
```

Which is used like so:

```
class Warrior:
    e_death = Event()
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

def death_printer(sender, **event_args):
    print(sender.name, 'has died!')

Warrior.e_death.add(death_printer)

warrior = Warrior('My Warrior')
warrior.e_death.fire(warrior)
```

The "problem" I want to solve is on the last line: `warrior.e_death.fire(warrior)`. I would like to not repeat the name of the object, so I could just do `warrior.e_death.fire()` instead of having to manually pass the `sender` to the event.
Is this possible in Python?

Answer (score 0):

I would change the Event class so that it accepts and stores a value for `sender` on instantiation:

```
class Event(set):
    def __init__(self, sender, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Event, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.sender = sender

    def fire(self, **event_args):
        for handler in self:
            handler(self.sender, *event_args)
```

and now instantiate that in the init for Warrior, rather than at class level:

```
class Warrior()
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Warrior, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.e_death = Event(self)
```

Now you can do `warrior.e_death.fire()`.

Comment: But this creates loads of extra `Event` instances! Instead of using just one and then passing the `sender` to a function as an argument